# Removing a parameter list from f(list) with preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

It seems to me that I saw something weird being done in a boost library and it ended up being exactly what I'm trying to do now.  Can't find it though...

I want to create a macro that takes a signature and turns it into a function pointer:

```
void f(int,int) {}

...
void (*x)(int,int) = WHAT( (f(int,int)) );

x(2,4); // calls f()
```

I especially need this to work with member function pointers so that WHAT takes two params:

```
WHAT(ClassType, (f(int,int)); // results in static_cast<void (ClassType::*)(int,int)>(&ClassType::f)
```

It's not absolutely necessary in order to solve my problem, but it would make things a touch nicer.

---

This question has nothing, per-se, to do with function pointers.  What needs to be done is to use the preprocessor to take "f(int,int)" and turn it into two different parts:

'f'
'(int,int)'

---

Why:

I've solved the problem brought up here: [Generating Qt Q_OBJECT classes pragmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320002/generating-qt-q-object-classes-pragmatically/4328105#4328105)

I've started a series of articles explaining how to do it:
http://crazyeddiecpp.blogspot.com/2011/01/quest-for-sane-signals-in-qt-step-1.html
http://crazyeddiecpp.blogspot.com/2011/01/quest-for-sane-signals-in-qt-step-2.html

The signature must be evaluated from, and match exactly, the "signal" that the user is attempting to connect with.  Qt users are used to expressing this as `SIGNAL(fun(param,param))`, so something like `connect_static(SIGINFO(object,fun(param,param)), [](int,int){})` wouldn't feel too strange.

In order to construct the signature I need to be able to pull it out of the arguments supplied.  There's enough information to get the member function address (using C++0x's decltype) and fetch the signature in order to generate the appropriate wrapper but I can't see how to get it out.  The closest I can come up with is `SIGINFO(object, fun, (param,param))`, which is probably good enough but I figured I'd ask here before considering it impossible to get the exact syntax I'd prefer.

Comment: Hmm, I originally misunderstood... So it explicitely needs to be the argument "(f(int,int))" - are these being generated somehow?

Comment: Good question, I once also had a similar requirement. Waiting for answer.

Comment: You may be able to solve this problem with `boost::function_traits` and `boost::function_types::parameter_types`, I'm not sure if it satisfies the preprocessor stipulation, however.

Comment: Won't work.  It happens at the wrong time.  In order to get the traits for the function I have to turn 'f(int,int)' into a function pointer.  In order to do that, I need 'f' alone.  function traits will definitely have their part to play but first I need to split this source string and the only way I can think of that might is the preprocessor.

Comment: I don't think I saw anything like that. The preprocessor has absolutely zero capabilities to manipulate the argument. As far as I know, boost is only taking apart parenthesized sublists.

Comment: Have you looked at the Boost.Preprocessor library? (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) I don't know if it actually contains a solution for your problem since I tend to avoid using the preprocessor, but it seems to have quite a collection of preprocessor tools.

Comment: @Ferruccio - I have, but an answer that shows I missed something would certainly be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do is impossible using standard preprocessor, unfortunately. There are a couple of reasons:

- It is impossible to split parameters passed to a macro using custom character. They have to be comma delimited. Otherwise that could solve your problem instantly.
- You cannot use preprocessor to define something that is not an identifier. Otherwise you could use double expansion where `(` and `)` is defined as `,` and split arguments on that as if it was passed as `f, int, int,`, then process it as variadic arguments.
- Function pointer definition in C++ does not allow you to deduce the name given to defined type, unfortunately.

Going even further, even if you manage to create a function pointer, the code won't work for methods because in order to invoke a method, you need to have two pointers - pointer to the method and to the class instance. This means you have to have some wrapper around this stuff.

That is why QT is using its own tools like `moc` to generate glue code.

The closes thing you might have seen in Boost is probably Signals, Bind and Lambda libraries. It is ironic that those libraries are much more powerful than what you are trying to achieve, but at the same time they won’t allow you to achieve it the way you want it. For example, even if you could do what you want with the syntax you want, you won’t be able to “connect” a slot to a “signal” if signal has a different signature. At the same time, libraries from Boost I mentioned above totally allow that. For example, if your “slot” expects more parameters than “signal” provides, you can bind other objects to be passed when “slot” is invoked. Those libraries can also suppress extra parameters if “slot” does not expect them.

I’d say the best way from C++ prospective as for today is to use Boost Signal approach to implement event handling in GUI libraries. QT doesn’t use it for a number of reasons. First, it started in like 90-s when C++ was not that fancy. Plus, they have to parse your code in order to work with “slots” and “signals” in graphic designer.

It seems for me than instead of using macros or even worse – non-standard tools on top of C++ to generate code, and using the following:

```
void (*x)(int,int) = WHAT( (f(int,int)) );
```

It would be much better to do something like this:

```
void f (int x, int y, int z);
boost::function<void (int, int)> x = boost::bind (&f, _1, _2, 3);
x (1, 2);
```

Above will work for both functions and methods.